# How to make a personal cooldown using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there a way to make a cooldown for each person? I've tried many options, but they tend to bug and make it like everyone used the command, not just one person. My code so far:

```
const talkedRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "The bot will respond with pong",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this (modified to your needs):

```
const talkedRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "The bot will respond with pong",
    execute(message, args){
        var cooldown = '15000' // cooldown in miliseconds
        var cooldownMessage = 'this command has a 15 seconds cooldown'

        if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.reply(`${cooldownMessage}`);
        } else {
            // your code here:
            message.channel.send('pong!');

            talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => {
            // Removes the user from the set after the cooldown
            talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
            }, cooldown);
        }
    }
}
```